# Laravel 5 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

As a L5 newbie I have 2 buttons as previous and next. I am using them to get next or previous records and they are working properly but when i get the last record and click next i get `NotFoundHttpException` How can i prevent this ? Here is my controller method

```
public function aracislemler($id)
{
    $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);

    $previous = Vehicle::where('id', '<', $vehicle->id)->max('id');

    $next = Vehicle::where('id', '>', $vehicle->id)->min('id');

    return view('pages.aracislemler', compact('vehicle','previous','next'));
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have any middleware attached to the route?

Comment: Yes i do @user3158900

Comment: Are you by chance using that to make sure a vehicle with that id exists, otherwise redirecting somewhere else?  And would that somewhere else be causing the issue?

Comment: I dont think somewhere else is causing the issue. As you said i should check the vehicle existance but not sure how to make it

Comment: That is entirely up to you if you want to check that or not first.  It still doesn't explain why you get `NotFoundHttpException` which generally means the route wasn't found.  Can you physically look at the link which is generated for the next page when you are on the last page?  Perhaps the id just isn't getting filled in and you don't have a route which will handle the URL without the id.  Try creating another route just like this one except without the id parameter just to test and see if anything changes.

Comment: Yes the id is not getting filled that is the problem.

Comment: Why not use pagination which gives you methods for automatically generating navigation, checking if they're more pages etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Prev/Next variables to handle the case when there is no previous or next ID.  For example:

```
if (!$previous = Vehicle::where('id', '<', $vehicle->id)->max('id')) {
    $previous = FALSE;
}


if (!$next = Vehicle::where('id', '>', $vehicle->id)->min('id')) {
    $next = FALSE;
}
```

Then in your view/html have something like:

```
<?php if($next): ?>
    <a href="url/<?= $next ?>">NEXT</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```